# bash hook that diverts commands preventing their execution (debug trap?)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What I need to accomplish, as part of a didactic tool, is to divert interactive bash commands to a daemon I'm writing (so far, so good. Thanks to  [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec)).

But I need the shell to actually ignore that command, which in turn will be evaluated and executed by my daemon.

**Is there any way for preexec functions to modify what will the shell actually execute?**

I've unsuccessfully tried to do so: I've figured "mangling BASH_COMMAND should do" (prepending a hash, overwriting it with a colon, etc). But NO, and I'm stuck with this. Apparently there is a scope issue I can't comprehend.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

An anonymous hint suggested that a non-zero result from preexec could do the trick (avoiding the execution altogether, not modifying the command).

That's the solution.

References:

- [stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285669/bash-cancelling-the-execution-of-trap-handler-debug)
- [BASH reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin-1)